# Swift UIImage convert as PDFDocument with PDFKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, pdfkit, pdfdocument

In my app i want to make PDFDocument from array of images, i use code below for this purpose, but my app crashes because of memory runs out, i used autoreleasepool but that doesn't help. What should i do?

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit


extension Array where Element: UIImage {
    
      func makePDF()-> PDFDocument? {
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
        for (index,image) in self.enumerated() {
            let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image)
            pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage!, at: index)
        }
        return pdfDocument
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it largely depends on the size of the images you are using. Try using JPEG images with quality 75-90%. And of course reduce image size to what your PDF really needs (usually you don't really need an original high resolution image in PDF)

Comment: actually i did but this doesn't solve a problem, even if i compress quality of images, if i need a pdf from 100 images the memory will run out